# Почему "званый" с одной Н?

Tags: морфология, прилагательные, причастия

> Народу всякого, *зва**н**ого* и *незва**н**ого*
> набралось множество.

Почему эти слова являются прилагательными? Ведь они не выражают постоянного признака предмета, а временный и применимый только к данному событию (*незва**нн**ый* на эту встречу человек).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы являться прилагательным, глагольная форма должна приобрести качественный признак.

Именно такой признак мы видим при образовании прилагательных от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида: званый - это желательный, а не только получивший приглашение. Не стоит понимать это слово исключительно в прямом смысле.

При наличии зависимых слов мы имеем  причастие: званные к обеду гости (этих уж точно позвали к обеду).

Comment: И тогда НЕ будет писаться раздельно: "не званный на эту встречу человек"